# Passing String Variables to MSExcel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a macro that will read a cell value from a named range, then modify that value by adding a prefix, then passing it to a Range call.

Basically, I have a dropdown used to select a tier, then upon execution of the macro, it should select a sheet, then unhide a range based on that.

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim StrSheetSelect As String
Set rCell = Range("ProjectTier")
Dim Tier As String
Dim rTier As Range


' Sheet 1 - Assess and Initiate

Set Tier = "AI+'rCell'"
Set rTier = Tier

StrSheetSelect = "1. Assess and Initiate"
Sheets(StrSheetSelect).Select
ActiveSheet.Range("Tier").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
ActiveSheet.Range("Tier").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>NA", Operator:=xlAnd
```

I get an "object required" error on the "Set Tier" function.
I'm very unfamiliar with excel vba and vb in general

Thanks!

Comment: To fix the error change `Set Tier = "AI+'rCell'"` to `Tier = "AI+'rCell'"` (remove the "Set" - this is just a string, not an object). But you will probably have more issues because you'll have to use the actual name of the named range in all statements with `ActiveSheet.Range("Tier")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a few problems. First, "Set" is only used with objects. In VBA Strings are built-in types, not objects. So the line throwing the error should start:

```
Tier = "AI ...
```

Then the RHS is a literal string, but it looks like trying to get the value from rCell. Also, to join strings use '&' not '+'. Try something like

```
Tier = "AI" & rCell.Value
```

Then to convert that to a range you'll need something like:

```
Set rTier = Range(Tier)
```

Hope that helps